# Best way to structure my desired, simple HTML layout

Tags: css, html

The image below shows the simple structure I hope to accomplish.The problem I am having is that I am wondering what the best way to structure the second row is - I want to have a background colour spanning the entire width of the page, but I want to split this row into two columns, which are in the centre of the document, and which will stay in the centre a you resize the webpage. How can I do this?

I assume I can then put a margin-top on the image.

[image: Image showing a document with 3 rows, the first one is simple, the second is split into two columns split down the middle. The column on the left has an arrow which points towards the third row.]

Here is my attempt thus far :

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="webpageLogo.png" alt="imageOfLogo" width="125" height="125"/>
        </div>
        <div id="twoCol">
            <div id="left">
                <p>TextBox Here.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="right"> 
                <img src="images/laptop.png" alt="An image of a laptop" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">

</div>
```

CSS :

```
#wrapper
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#twoCol
{
    height : 400px; 
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
}

#left
{
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
}

#right
 {
     float:right;
     text-align:left;
}

#twoCol{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
```

However, the second row here is not displaying as I wish and is not resizing for me. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been building stuff like this since before Bootstrap so I'd build it by hand, personally. I'd do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SAYtS/

Instead of wrapping the whole page in a containing div, do each page section separately and then add a common `.page` div within each one to set the width and central alignment consistently throughout the document. Then you can us `display:inline-block` to get the two columns. You could also float the two divs but you'd probably end up needing to use the clearfloat (http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) fix to prevent the wrapper div from collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at using a grid system like bootstrap grid.

It makes life so much easier in so many ways to do exactly what you're trying to do, plus it can resize and even adjust to mobile..

Take the 10-15 minutes to understand how to use it, it saves hours later on trying to hack css code to make things work.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/twitter-bootstrap-101-the-grid/

http://www.revillwebdesign.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/